# Proof that G is a Tree After DFS and BFS form the same tree T

Tags: algorithms, graphs, proof-techniques, correctness-proof, check-my-answer

Let G be a connected, undirected graph containing some vertex s. let's say  that  BFS  and  DFS  are  both  run  on  G starting  at  s and  that  the  breadth  first  search  and  depth
first search trees produced are the same.  Show that G is a tree.

Would this be good enough?

In order to show that G is a tree  Let us denote the tree produced by BFS and DFS be T.
Assume that G is not a tree, which means there must be an edge (u, v) ∈ G and such that (u, v) $\not\in $ T. ( G has more edges than T)

In such case, as the DFS tree forming, there will be a backedge.  That implies there is a cycle in G . That is because if v is discovered  first by DFS,  DFS must also find V later before finishing explore v.

On the other hand,  as the BFS tree forming, u and v can only differ by one level, which means there is not cycle.

With the fact that BFS and DFS tree are the same tree, it implies that one of u and v is an ancestor of the other and they can only differ by  one level. Therefore, all edges connecting T are the same as connecting G and G is a tree.

Comment: This question appears to be unsuited for this site because questions of the form: "This is the exercise problem, this is my solution. Please grade!" are not interesting for anyone but you. Please see [this related meta discussion](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/597/), and [these hints](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/) on asking questions about exercise problems. If you want to ask a *specific* question about a *specific* part of your attempt, please edit the question accordingly and it may be reopened. Otherwise, you might want to visit [chat] and get some feedback there.